# Sendin a basic email with C# through exchange on my web form

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, email, webforms

Hi I have extremely basic knowledge in C# but my manager needs a from that is c# that send an email through exchange all it does is pulls the information from the fields (Which works fine). All I need to do now is get it to concatenate the variables it collected and send it as an email. The concatenation is fine it is just the email part. How do I go about setting up an email sender in C#

Comment: You can do this using `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38750/A-Simple-But-Effective-Way-to-Send-an-Email-using

Comment: I have been looking on the internet of course :'), I am just having problems getting them to work and they are kind of irrelevant because I never even got them partially working so there is not point in using them as my example when I need a new approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use code like this one:

```
    public void Send(string address, string subject, string body, string from, bool isHtml)
    {
        using (var message = new MailMessage(from, address))
        {
            message.Subject = subject;
            message.Body = body;
            message.IsBodyHtml = isHtml;

            using (var client = new SmtpClient("EX2010.yourdomain.com", 25 /* default port */))
            {
                client.EnableSsl = false;
                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user@yourdomain.com", "password");
                client.Send(message);
            }
        }
    }
```

You must set exchange host, port and credentials.

Comment: Can you give me an example with ports in I'm just trying to wrap my head around it, I want to do it withing a If statement like so `if(sendEmail){  ....Send email here }`

Comment: Port for SMTP is 25 by default. You can ask your company's administrator for host name of exchange server.

Comment: For using method you should write smth like: `if (sendEmail){ Send("touser@somedomain.com", "Your subject", "Body of e-mail", "fromuser@yourdomain.com", false); }`